# Conditionally include provided scope dependencies with sbt and the universal plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a project that is a scala & scalatra API.  I have two distributables that I build with [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) -

1. RPM & DEB install for on-premise installations
2. heroku install for cloud installations

I'm currently using `provided` scope dependencies for items I need to manually manage with the RPM/DEB approach - database libraries that I cannot bundle and distribute due to license restrictions.

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.30" % "provided",
"com.microsoft" % "sqlserver.jdbc" % "4.1" % "provided",
..etc..
```

This has been working great.  I use the universal plugin and the `dist` task, somewhat massaged, and then hook up some package build scripts.

Now I'm building the heroku install, and I don't know how to add back in those provided dependencies.  I'm using the universal plugin and running the `stage` task.  However, provided dependencies are being filtered out and I'd like to actually have them included when running `stage`, because I don't have the license restriction anymore in heroku.

Options that I think I have...

1. Add a `mapping` to add back in provided scope dependencies during the `stage` task, but not during the `dist` task
2. Drop provided scope entirely and manually exclude those dependencies from the packaging process during `dist`

I have some mappings already like this,

```
//add webapp dir to zip
mappings in Universal ++= directory("src/main/webapp")

//add db dir to zip, but move it into /lib/db instead of /db
mappings in Universal ++= (directory("src/main/resources/db").map{t => 
    (t._1, "lib/"+t._2)
  }
)
```

So I feel like I could probably figure out how to add/exclude if I really tried, but I'm having problems finding any documentation for this stuff.  The examples [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#mapping-examples) don't really help much, or I don't understand enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting question. Some time ago we added the possibility to [add arbitrary artifacts](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/commit/80ce656ab248f4d9a1c6635168bf71f87fb4435f) from the build classpath. ( See [scaladocs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/latest/api/#com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper$) too )

Option 1 could look like this. Note, that this doesn't work as I expect, as some mappings are not exactly picked up by native-packager:

```
// `show universal::stage:mappings` works properly
mappings in (Universal, stage) ++= {
  // calculate provided dependencies.
  val compileDep = (managedClasspath in Compile).value.toSet
  val runtimeDep = (managedClasspath in Runtime).value.toSet
  val provided = compileDep -- runtimeDep

  // create mappings
  fromClasspath(provided.toSeq, "jar", artifact => true)
}
```

I suggest a variation of option 1 by providing a [build environment](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/package_configuration.html#sbt-parameters-and-build-environment) and decided, which mappings to add.

```
mappings in Universal ++= {
  // a build environment
  val env = buildEnv.value

  // calculate provided dependencies.
  val compileDep = (managedClasspath in Compile).value.toSet
  val runtimeDep = (managedClasspath in Runtime).value.toSet
  val provided = compileDep -- runtimeDep

  // create mappings, depending on build environment
  fromClasspath(provided.toSeq, "jar", _ => env == BuildEnv.Stage)
}

// add the dependencies to the start script as well
scriptClasspath ++= { /* similar code as above */}
```

### What I would like to have done

I hoped to be able to to something like this

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0" % "provided"

mappings in (Universal, stage) ++= fromClasspath(
   (managedClasspath in Compile).value,
   "jar",
    artifact => artifact.scope == "provided"
)
```

Which wasn't possible, as the [sbt Artifact](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Artifacts.html) has no way to access the ivy-scope (or I haven't found it).

Then I tried to do this

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0" % "provided" extra("heroku" -> "true")

mappings in (Universal, stage) ++= fromClasspath(
   (managedClasspath in Compile).value,
   "jar",
    artifact => artifact.extra.find(_ == "heroku")
      .map(_.toBoolean)
      .getOrElse(false)
)
```

which didn't worked either, as it seems that SBT doesn't pass the `extra` attributes from the [ModuleID](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.11/api/index.html#sbt.ModuleID) to the [Artifact](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.11/api/index.html#sbt.Artifact) model. This left me with the solution described above.

Comment: Seems like it did the trick, thanks a lot for your help.  I was able to add some filtering to tweak the results and we are off and running.  Sad about sbt Artifact - you'd think there should be ability to get access to this sort of information in-band rather than make another configuration item!

Comment: Actually this didn't quite work out - it added the mappings files but didn't manage to add them to the run script's classpath entries.. Trying to figure that one out now

Comment: Added them using scriptClasspath ++= { ..same stuff.. }

Comment: Awesome @lucas ! Sorry I didn't thought of that :(